# Launching MS Word from elevated process leads to "run-time error 429"

Tags: command-line, microsoft-word, uac

Weird problem. I'm trying to open a word doc from a command prompt.

```
C:\> \somefolder\SomeWordDoc.docx
```

If I do this from a normal prompt, it works fine. However, if I have launched the prompt with Administrator rights, then I get this dialog:

```
Run-time error '429':
ActiveX component can't create object.
```

What's going on here, and is there an easy fix?

Comment: What version of MS Office are you using? I can't reproduce it on Windows 8.1 with MS Office 2010 Professional.

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit, Office Home and Business 2013

Comment: Would this page be of any help to you? https://support.microsoft.com/kb/828550

Comment: Nope, not automating anything... just launching. :-/ I have found a workaround: `explorer.exe [document path]` works OK, but would still like to know what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry I can't be of more help to you

Answer (score 2):

If you can run it in [Office's Safe Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/work-with-office-safe-modes-HP010354300.aspx) (ie: `word.exe /safe`) as the administrator, then it's probably an ActiveX plugin of some kind that's not multi-user aware, or isnt' fully Office 2013 compatible.

You'll need to determine which plugin it is that's causing the error (most likely a plugin by a 3rd party, like you anti-virus provider or something), and ensure it's also installed/available in the administrator user's context on that machine. If that can't be done, then ensure it's updated to the latest version and hope they added compatibility.  If that can't be done, perhaps just disable the plugin permanently.